# Magento custom Product Attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I add an attribute type `Yes/No` `is_special` to product.

(I want to just logged user can see special products.)

Then, I open some products and set to `Yes` But when I show it on front end, All is `No`.

I clear cache and `reindex` before. But It still `No`

Please help me guys. I am very grateful to You...!!

Thanks In Advance...!!

Answer (score 0):

When attributes are added, they are added to the database and magento caches the calls to certain databases. Try deleting your cache folder in var/cache and see if that helps.

Comment: It still is 'No' for all product. :(
Thanks your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new product attribute, you have a lot of options, a few changing the loading bahavious "Show in product listing" sets the collection to load this on the category pages, "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" loads the attribute on the product view page.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add featured/special product attribute to magento. Please refer my tutorial which explains how to add yes/no attribute.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/adding-custom-product-attributes-in-magento/

Then you filter the featured products using the code in phtml.

```
<?php
$featuredProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', 1)
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
?>
```